# Consulta con estado de react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Actualmente estoy creando un mini-editor de bbcodes propio para mi aplicación en ReactJS. Utilizo componentes funcionales. En el  archivo TextEditor.jsx tengo el siguiente código que maneja el textarea.

```
    const [bbcodeText, setBbcodeText] = useState("");

    const update = (e) => {
        setSelection(null);
        setBbcodeText(e.target.value);
        if (typeof props.onChange == 'function') {
            props.onChange(e.target.value);
        }
    }

    <textarea className="form-input forum__body-input" ref={textAreaRef} value={bbcodeText} onChange={update} />
```

Lo anterior funciona correctamente, sin embargo instalé [emoji-mart][1] para tener acceso a la opción de colocar emojis en el textarea, para lo cual uso el siguiente código:

```
    const handleEmoji = (emoji) => {
        let newText = bbcodeText + " " + emoji.native;
        setBbcodeText(newText);
    }
    <Picker title="Emojis" emoji="grinning" set='apple'  style={{width: '100%'}} onSelect={handleEmoji} />
```

El textarea se actualiza correctamente, el problema es que este componente TextEditor lo acceso desde un componente padre de la forma:

```
const [bbcode, setBBcode] = useState();
<TextEditor onChange={update} />
```

El problema ocurre por si selecciono un emoji y trato de acceder al estado "bbcode" el resultado es una cadena vacía, pero si escribo algo posterior a ello, ya se muestra el emoji con el texto al final, es decir, necesito disparar el onChange para que se muestre los datos actualizados.

Lo que ocupo saber es uan guía de como poder obtener el estado actualizado, si solo quiero por ejemplo insertar emojis en el textarea.

Gracias.

---

En el componente padre donde instancio TextEditor tengo lo siguiente:

```
 const [bbcode, setBBcode] = useState();
 const update = (v) => {
    setBBcode(v);
};


const handlePost = async() => {
    console.log(bbcode)
}
<TextEditor onChange={update}  onSelect={handleEmoji} />
<button className="button purple" onClick={handlePost}>Agregar respuesta</button>
```

En este caso bbcode me retorna undefined si solo uso "emojis" pero si escribo texto funciona correctamente.
[1]: https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart

Comment: Mencionas que hay un problema al tratar de acceder al estado `bbcode`, pero no queda claro cómo se están usando `bbcode` y  `setBBcode` , no se están pasando como `props` en el componente `TextEditor`.

Comment: @g.4 he actualizado el mensaje con el contenido del componente padre, y el comportamient que tiene bbcode, que en este caso es retornar undefined en caso de solo usar emojis, pero retorna el contenido bien si después de un emoji escribo texto normal en el textarea. Gracias!